# How to get Windows Adobe Web Premium CS3 to run on a Mac?

Tags: windows, adobe

I spent about $1,600 for Adobe Web Premium cs3 (Windows version) back in the day. How can I get this to run on my Mac without having to buy a Mac license?

Sorry, I refuse to pay a subscription for new versions of stuff I bought and it still does the job.

Comment: It does the job on a Windows machine not on OSX. If you need it professionally then this is a cost you have to put up with when changing from Windows to OSX

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to pay for a Windows license and either dual boot or run in an emulator like Parallels or VMWare. Even if you could get trade for a Mac-specific version of the software you bought, CS3 isn't going to work well on anything other than older versions of OS X.

Comment: I will try with the free windows 90 day trials. Then try create a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get a Mac license of CS3 from Adobe.  The software is 9-10 years old and Adobe has no interest in supporting anything but their CC offerings.

Your best bet is to see if you can get an old copy from the secondary market like eBay.